# AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items' Error (Djngo Rest Api)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

**The following code has been written but still, the following error will happen:**

VIEWS PAGE

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import serializers,status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import AccountSerializer
import requests, json

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,'register.html')

def register(request):
    return render(request,'register.html')

def login(request):
    return render(request,'login.html')

@api_view(['POST'])
def registeruser(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        SaveSerialize = AccountSerializer(data=request.data)
        if SaveSerialize.is_valid():
            SaveSerialize.save()
            return Response(SaveSerialize.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(SaveSerialize.data,status=status.HTTP_404_BAD_REQUEST)

def insertemp(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        gender = request.POST.get('gender')
        pass1 = request.POST.get('password1')
        pass2 = request.POST.get('password2')
        if pass1 == pass2:
            password = pass1
        address1 = request.POST.get('address1')
        address2 = request.POST.get('address2')
        city = request.POST.get('city')
        branch = request.POST.get('branch')
        address = f'{address1} {address2} {city} {branch}'
        data = {
            'name':name,
            'email':email,
            'gender':gender,
            'password':password,
            'address':address,
        }

        headers={'Content-Type: application/json'}
        read = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/registeruser', json=data, headers=headers)
        return render(request,'register.html')
    else:
        return render(request,'register.html')
```

**This is the serializer page:**

```
SERIALIZER PAGE:

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Account


class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = "__all__"


MODELS PAGE:

from django.db import models
from django.db.models.base import Model

# Create your models here.
class Account(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address=models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

URLS PAGE:

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('register',views.register,name='register'),
    path('login',views.login,name='login'),
    path('registeruser',views.registeruser,name='registeruser'),
    path('insertemp',views.insertemp,name='insertemp'),
]
```

**this is following error occuring :**

```
AttributeError at /insertemp
'set' object has no attribute 'items'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/insertemp
Django Version: 4.0
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'set' object has no attribute 'items'
Exception Location: H:\Projects\Advance_projects\STEPON\Login\env\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py, line 451, in prepare_headers
Python Executable:  H:\Projects\Advance_projects\STEPON\Login\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.1
Python Path:    
['H:\\Projects\\Advance_projects\\STEPON\\Login\\login',
 'C:\\Users\\sagar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\sagar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\sagar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\sagar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',
 'H:\\Projects\\Advance_projects\\STEPON\\Login\\env',
 'H:\\Projects\\Advance_projects\\STEPON\\Login\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Comment: `headers={'Content-Type: application/json'}` is a set type, not a dict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo. Instead of:

```py
headers={'Content-Type: application/json'}
```

you need this:

```py
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

Comment: thank you so much! you saved my day.

Comment: Glad to help and welcome to Stack Overflow :) Consider marking this answer as right if it helped.